# Initializing boost::random::discrete_distribution in VC2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, random, tr1

I am trying to implement one of the first examples from **boost::random** documentation in Visual Studio 2010 SP1, using the native  library (TR1).

Before when using the  library, I found out that I can just use the built in VC2010 random functions and they work just like the boost ones, but here I cannot use the native functions.

The problem is with initializing `discrete_distribution<>` in VC2010. In Boost it takes an array:

```
double probabilities[] =
{
    0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
};
boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist( probabilities );
```

But in VC2010 I don't know what I should supply it with. Here is the error I receive at compiling:

> Reason: cannot convert from 'double [6]' to 'const std::tr1::discrete_distribution<>::param_type'
>
> No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

I thought that as these functions are implemented in VC2010 I can just use the built in ones while preserving multi-platform compatibility, but it seems I have to fall back on using the boost classes.

**Are there any performance penalties for using boost::random** over the built in  class in VC2010?

**Is it generally a recommended idea to stick with Boost  libraries, even if they are implemented in most of the C++ compilers now?**

Here are two pastebins of the working and the non-working code:

[Non-working modified example using std](http://pastebin.com/L1Be4Q3t)

[Working original example using boost::random](http://pastebin.com/VMWrDjiz)

Also, what does this line means on the [boost doc page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_random/tutorial.html)?

> Tip If your compiler supports std::initializer_list, you can
> initialize discrete_distribution directly with the weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VC2010's `std::tr1::discrete_distribution` doesn't conform to the latest C++11 spec (hence the namespace `tr1`), and doesn't yet provide all the ways to construct it. In matter of fact, it seems that the only way to construct it in VC2010 is by either default-initializing it, or by providing a generator that gets called N times: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462277.aspx

The constructor that takes `const param_type&` is essentially the same thing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee462364.aspx

In the actual C++11 specification, there are two more overloads for the constructor of `discrete_distribution`, namely one that takes two input iterators, and one that takes a `std::initializer_list`, which brings us to your second question.

> Tip If your compiler supports std::initializer_list, you can initialize discrete_distribution directly with the weights.

`std::initializer_list` is a [new C++11 feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Initializer_lists), that basically allows you to initialize not only arrays and POD structs with an initializer list, but also more complex class types by having constructors take a `std::initializer_list` (they can also be used for other purposes than initializing new objects though). The Wikipedia entry has more information, and the idea is quite straight-forward so I won't go into more detail here. But basically it means that instead of doing:

```
double probabilities[] =
{
    0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1
};
boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist( probabilities );
```

You can just do:

```
boost::random::discrete_distribution<> dist( {0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1} );
```

The construct inside the constructor parameter list constructs a `std::initializer_list<double>` and then passes it to the `boost::random::discrete_distribution<>` constructor.

The reason why VC2010 doesn't support this yet is simply because VC2010 does not support `std::initializer_list` yet (it only has partial C++11 support).

That all being said, the current implementation of VC2010's `std::tr1::discrete_distribution` seems to be pretty lacking, and the only way to initialize it seems to be via a generator function, so I would stick to the boost version myself.

Even assuming you were using a compiler that fully conforms to the C++11 specification, Boost still has a **lot** to offer. In no way does C++11 offer everything that boost has to offer you, and there's no reason to ditch boost completely when using C++11. However if you are writing C++11 code it obviously makes sense to use the C++11 equivalents of the facilities that it does offer over the boost versions as they may have vendor specific optimizations.

Many people still choose C++03 over C++11, since it'll be quite some time until C++11 is fully supported by all the major compiler manufacturers, so in cases like this the boost equivalents of the facilities that C++11 also offers you are still quite useful.